# React Native Expo is stuck between specific lines of code

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, freeze

I'm writing an app using React Native and Expo, which integrates with Firebase.
In my app, I have the following function, which uploads an image to the Storage service, and some data regarding that image to Firestore:

```js
/**
 * Upload image and data.
 * @param {string} uri Image URI. (file://)
 * @param {{x: number, y: number}} ratings Number ratings (1-5)
 * @param {string} review Text review.
 * @param {LocationObject} location Location object.
 * @return {Promise<string|boolean>} A string containing the image id if is successful, otherwise `false`.
 */
async function uploadReview(uri, ratings, review, location) {
  let updatedStorage = false;
  let imageId;
  try {
    imageId = Date.now() + uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('.'));
    let sTime = Date.now();
    const storageRef = storage()
        .ref()
        .child('images/' + auth().currentUser.uid + '/' + imageId);

    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    await storageRef.put(blob);
    console.log('Uploaded image in ' + (Date.now() - sTime) + 'ms');
    updatedStorage = true;

    sTime = Date.now();
    await firestore().collection('users').doc(auth().currentUser.uid).collection('reviews')
        .doc(imageId.toString()).set({
          x: ratings.x,
          y: ratings.y,
          review: review,
          imageId: imageId,
          location: new firestore.GeoPoint(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude),
        });
    console.log('Uploaded review in ' + (Date.now() - sTime) + 'ms'); // --- 1 ---

    console.log('Review uploaded successfully'); // --- 2 ---

    return imageId;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);

    try {
      if (updatedStorage) {
        const storageRef = storage()
            .ref()
            .child('images/' + auth().currentUser.uid + '/' + imageId);
        await storageRef.delete();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERROR DELETING FAILED UPLOAD: ' + imageId);
      console.log(e);
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that when this function is called, it gets to the line marked with `---1---`, but for some reason it (usually) hangs there, and does not continue to the line marked with
`---2---` (without any errors or whatever, it's just stuck).
If I remove line `---1---` (which I placed there only for some testing), and only keep line `---2---`, then it simply stops after that one, and does not get to the line where I return `imageId`.
Also, when this happens the app is half irresponsive. When I tap the back button, it does the usual animation, and does not seem to be frozen or anything, but in reality it is, and does nothing.

Another issue is that sometimes the app takes an insane amount of time to upload to Firestore - can reach up to a few minutes, for just 2 numbers, 2 short strings, and one GeoPoint, so it's not like I'm uploading some 10 TB data. (And uploading the Storage is always fine, no problem with that one)

I have tried cleaning gradle with `gradlew clean`, and then rebuilding, but it didn't help. I've restarted my phone a few times, the PC, but the problem persists.

I'm really clueless on what can be the cause of this, I've never encountered a code which simply does not continue to run to the next line.
Does anyone have any idea on what's happening it, how can I fix it?

(I'm running on a physical Android device, and am using some native libraries, so this is an Expo Development Build)

Comment: Will uri always be an image? If so, you could change the logic of your function a bit. You could add that URL in the document and use a cloud function to upload it to Storage. That way you won't depend on your user's internet to download an image, which may be large and will make your app faster, since it won't download an image and keep the blob in memory.

Comment: Regarding the firestore timing, does it happen throughout the application or just in that function?

Comment: @GabrielNexT Yes, URI always is an image, and it is an image the user takes with his camera, not one I download from the internet, so it is not necessary to create a cloud function for it. And for the Firestore timing, except for this one, the only other place where I use Firestore is when reading a "review" object from it (like the one I'm uploading here), and it works just fine there.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll think about it a bit and if I come to a conclusion I'll comment.